# WPF : Animating user Control on load

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am developing an application in which  I have a user control inside a window. I want to perform some growing animation on the size of that control when it gets attached to the window.
Can anyone help me with it ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your styling:

```
<YourControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="YourControl.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="150" Duration="0:0:5" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:5" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</YourControl.Triggers>
```

Comment: Specifying `Storyboard.TargetName` is not needed for this.

Comment: Could convert it into the C# code pls? I have got some trouble with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181759/wpf-usercontrol-animation-in-c-sharp