# Custom animation in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, windows-phone-8

I have to animate Bottom Margin of my element but there is no "ThicknessAnimation" in Windows Phone 8, what should I do?

Comment: What you should do: clarify your question

Comment: I have a Grid, at first when it initializes it's margin is set to (0,0,0, -Grid.Height)to disappear the grid. after loading, I need to animate bottom margin to Zero in order to appear the grid

Comment: Have a look [at this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869597/wpf-animating-user-control-on-load).

Answer (score 0):

You want define a `Storyboard` animation that tweens the Property value you want to modify.

For example, take a look at my sample Animation on a `Polygon`.  I like using a `RenderTransform` to move the `UIElement` around rather than using a `Margin` like you're doing.

```XAML
<Polygon x:Name="MyPolygon" Points="0,0 40,70 150,70 110,0" Stroke="LimeGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
</Polygon>
```

So the `Storyboard` is pretty simple

Stick this in the `Page.Resources` or `Application.Resources`

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard1" Storyboard.TargetName="MyPolygon"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.000">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="300">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Then you can just call it in your function

```C#
MyStoryboard1.begin();
```